# Função que insere dados no banco

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, funções

estou com este pequeno problema, não importa o que eu faça não da certo, sempre fica dando "Query inválida", alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
   <?php
include('conexao.php');
include('fecha_conexao.php');

function inserir($coluna,$valor,$tabela){
    error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
    //perguntando se é um array
    if((is_array($coluna)) and (is_array($valor))){
        //perguntando se tem o mesmo número de elementos
        if(count($coluna) == count($valor)){
            //query de inserção no banco
            $inserir = "INSERT INTO {$tabela}(".implode(', ',$coluna).") VALUES('".implode('\', \'',$valor)."')";

            }else{
                return false;
                }

        }else{
            $inserir = "INSERT INTO {$tabela}({$coluna}) VALUES ('{$valor}')";
            }
            if($connect =connect()){
                if(mysql_query($inserir,$connect)){
                    fechaConexao($connect);
                    echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso";
                    return true;
                    }else{
                        echo"Query Inválida!";
                        return false;
                        }
                }else{
                    return false;
                    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Dá um  `echo $inserir` que já é um começo.

Comment: Por favor, coloque o código como texto no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: dei um echo no $inserir e não apareceu nada

Comment: não utilize um include para fechar uma conexão. É um desperdicio de memoria. Feche a conexão, claro mas, com um `mysqli_close($conn);`

Answer (score 0):

Coloque seu **include('fecha_conexao.php');** no final do PHP porque me parece - pelo que o nome sugere - que ele fecha a conexão e o que vier pela frente não vai ser executado.

```
<?php
include('conexao.php');
function inserir($coluna,$valor,$tabela){
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
//perguntando se é um array
if((is_array($coluna)) and (is_array($valor))){
    //perguntando se tem o mesmo número de elementos
    if(count($coluna) == count($valor)){
        //query de inserção no banco
        $inserir = "INSERT INTO {$tabela}(".implode(', ',$coluna).") VALUES('".implode('\', \'',$valor)."')";

        }else{
            return false;
            }

    }else{
        $inserir = "INSERT INTO {$tabela}({$coluna}) VALUES ('{$valor}')";
        }
        if($connect =connect()){
            if(mysql_query($inserir,$connect)){
                fechaConexao($connect);
                echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso";
                return true;
                }else{
                    echo"Query Inválida!";
                    return false;
                    }
            }else{
                return false;
                }
}

 //by djva 1/06 às 13:36
 //Não utilize um include para fechar uma conexão. É um desperdicio de memoria. 
 //Feche a conexão, claro mas, com um mysqli_close($conn);
 //include('fecha_conexao.php');
 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```